# mysql connect doesn't work on command line

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, command-line, phpbb3

If I create php file and open it in browser with following content:

```
<?php
var_dump(function_exists("mysqli_connect"));
```

I receive:

```
bool(true)
```

but when I do it from ssh command line

```
php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("mysqli_connect"));'
```

I receive:

```
bool(false)
```

Why is that? I can use mysqli_connect / mysql_connect while operating my websites from browser, but can't on ssh.

I wanted to update my phpbb 3.0 to phpbb 3.1 [via the command line](https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/ug/upgradeguide/upgrade3/):

```
php ./bin/phpbbcli.php db:migrate --safe-mode
```

but as you see, I can't. The output is:

```
PHP Fatal error: SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]<br /><br />mysqli_connect function does not exist, is mysqli extension installed? []<br /><br />An sql error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact an administrator if this problem persists. in /zzzzzzzzz/phpbb/db/driver/driver.php on line 855
```

Of course my phpbb 3.0 board works well on mysqli. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved this or not, but try putting the full path to the php file like so

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.38/bin/php bin/phpbbcli.php db:migrate --safe-mode
```

as you might be executing a php version different from the one you have configured with mysql

Hope this helps someone